Defining a specific topology in Isabelle
I would like to be able to define any sort of topology in Isabelle, and I'm wondering how I can establish a topology for several sets of lemmas (is that a locale?). So if I want to want to work with the usual topology on R or R^n, how could I do this? Or, say the lower-limit topology?
I'm wondering if this is what the "Generators for toplogies" inside the  "HOL/Topological_Spaces.thy" theory is for.
Or if I want to write a lemma or definition that refers to an open set, I assume I need to specify the topology?  Or perhaps I can write lemmas and definitions which use the "open" predicate but without a specific topology which can then be checked against in the event I specify a topology?
